# Вывод текста js

Tags: javascript, json, текст

У меня есть строка в `json` файле:

`"Sotrudniki": "Петров (с 2012-05-05)\n" +"Иванов (с 2012-05-05)\n" +"Сидоров (с 2012-11-07)"`

Как сделать вывод только первой строки: ***Петров (с 2012-05-05)***, позже внизу появится кнопка показать всех, на которую нажимая можно увидеть остальных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {"Sotrudniki": "Петров (с 2012-05-05)\n" + "Иванов (с 2012-05-05)\n" + "Сидоров (с 2012-11-07)"}
console.log(data.Sotrudniki.split("\n")[0])
```

В json вроде не может быть операций типа сложения.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('"Петров (с 2012-05-05)\n" +"Иванов (с 2012-05-05)\n" +"Сидоров (с 2012-11-07)"'.replace('\n', '').split('+')[0])
```

Comment: Не совсем так, в консоли данные из json выводятся просто в столбец.
Есть предположение что нужно обрезать как-нибудь до \n , т.е. считывать одну строку. А потом вывести все остальные.

Comment: Добавил код убирающий \n

Answer (score 1):

Возможно более удобным будет следующий алгоритм работы с json-файлом.

- Прочитать файл с помощью fetch или xhr
- Получить из его содержимого объект или массив объектов.
- Обработать полученные данные средствами javascript

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(users => {
    showFirst(users, container);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });

function showFirst(users, container) {
  addUser(users[0], container);
  const showMoreButton = addShowMoreButton(container);
  showMoreButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    showAllUsers.bind(
      undefined,
      container,
      showMoreButton,
      users
    )
  );
}

function addUser(user, container) {
  const userBox = document.createElement('div');
  userBox.innerHTML = `
  <p>Name: <span>${user.name}</span></p>
  <p>Email: <span>${user.email}</span></p>
  `;
  container.appendChild(userBox);
  return userBox;
}

function addShowMoreButton(container) {
  const showMoreButton = document.createElement('button');
  showMoreButton.innerText = 'Show more...';
  container.appendChild(showMoreButton);
  return showMoreButton;
}

function removeElement(element) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function showAllUsers(container, showMoreButton, users) {
  removeElement(showMoreButton);
  for (let i = 1; i < users.length; i++) {
    addUser(users[i], container);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Интересно, больше спасибо за развернутый ответ!